# Java not detected by Banking Site

Tags: java

My banking site does not find java plug-in even though java.com reports java working properly.  Iam using Firefox and Chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 (64-bit).  I have installed Oracle Java 7u10 (64-bit) from webupd8 ppa.  Is this issue specific to the banking site ?   How do I get it working ?  However, when I access using FF/Chrome/IE on Windows XP, it works.

Comment: Which Bank's website?

Comment: Union Bank of India site: unionbankonline.co.in. It requires Java after one logs in to display another window using Java. It displays the error message "You need to install the latest Java Plugin. Please Click OK."

Comment: Sorry I do not have a union bank account to check it , but I found a message from their website that may be solve your problem. "If you are enabled for 2 Factor Authentication, then it is essential for you to install latest JAVA on your system."  So, disabling "2 Factor Authentication" may be work for you!

Comment: The real problem is the bank's IT people expect *your* computer to be running Messy Windoze, Internet Exploder, and probably a specific version of Java.  While they are trying to stop people having problems, they need to widen what their filter accepts as a valid browser and Java.  Write a letter to your bank and tell them that you have a brain and prefer not to use inferior products from software monopolists, are quite capable of implementing  a system that will read Java code correctly, and would prefer it if they didn't force their assumptions and biases on you. ;-)